# NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am new to Mathematica. I am working on solving the following different equations numerically written in the code as below.

```
www[x_] := Sin[x^2] 
NDSolve[{x'[t] == -3 www[x[t]] (x[t] - y[t]), y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 27 x[t] - y[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t]}, 
        {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 20}]; 
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. %], {t, 0, 20}, Frame -> True]
```

Where is my mistake and how fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I would guess that you had used '=' instead of '==' at some point in your session.  It is a common cause of the `NDSolve::ndode` error.  I don't get that error on the input you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake has nothing to do with *Mathematica*. For solving a differential equation numerically, you need to provide inital- (or boundary-) conditions.

Here is your code that runs. Please adapt it to your needs:

```
www[x_] := Sin[x^2]
NDSolve[{x'[t] == -3 www[x[t]] (x[t] - y[t]), 
   y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 27 x[t] - y[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t], 
   x[0] == 5, y[0] == 2, z[0] == 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 20}];

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. %], {t, 0, 20}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]